# Changing color according using condition in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui, switch-statement

I'm struggling to create this last design on my TicTacToe app. I would like to make the colour of the winning line change colour according to the winner player (green for .human, .red for computer and .blue for drawn).
Is there an easy way to add this conditional?
I'm a real beginner trying to learn Swift.

This part refers to the logic of the game:

```
func processPlayerMove(for position : Int) {
    if isSquareOccupied(in: moves, forIndex: position) { return }
    moves[position] = Move(player: .human, boardIndex: position)
    
    // check for win condition or draw
    if checkWinConditions(for: .human, in: moves) {
        alertItem = AlertContext.humanWin
        return
    }
    
    if checkForDraw(in: moves) {
        alertItem = AlertContext.draw
        return
    }
    
    isGameboardDisabled = true
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [self] in
        let computerPosition = determineComputerMovePosition(in: moves)
        moves[computerPosition] = Move(player: .computer, boardIndex: computerPosition)
        isGameboardDisabled = false
        
        if checkWinConditions(for: .computer, in: moves) {
            alertItem = AlertContext.computerWin
            return
    }
        
        if checkForDraw(in: moves) {
            alertItem = AlertContext.draw
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This part is about the design. I've tried to use conditional to make the colour change but I couldn't organize the code to change only the line of the winner, the full board changes and that's not what I want to happen.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: viewModel.colums, spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(0..<9) { i in
                    ZStack {
                        GameSquareView(proxy: geometry)
                            
                        Image(systemName: viewModel.moves[i]?.indicator ?? "")
                            .resizable()
                            .padding()
                            .background(Circle().fill((viewModel.moves[i] != nil) ? Color.primary.opacity(0) : Color(.secondarySystemBackground)))
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3 - 25, height: geometry.size.width/3 - 25)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.processPlayerMove(for: i)
                    }
```

That's what I tried to do:

```
Image(systemName: playerMoves[i]?.indicator ?? "")
                                .resizable()
                                .padding()
                                .background(Circle().fill((playerMoves[i] != nil) ? Color.primary.opacity(0) : Color(.secondarySystemBackground)))
                                .foregroundColor(checkWinConditions(for: .playerTwo, in: playerMoves) ? Color.green : Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                                .foregroundColor(checkForDraw(in: playerMoves) ? Color.blue : Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3 - 25, height: geometry.size.width/3 - 25)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                            
                        }
```

Comment: There's definitely a way to do it, but unfortunately, you haven't provided enough code to determine how it would work in your situation (you haven't shown any UI code, for instance). You could look into doing a computed property with a `switch` statement inside that returns a `Color` based on the state of another variable.

Comment: Thank you, jnpdx! I edited it with more information. I tried the switch statement, but it didn't work, I think it might be because I didn't do it right. I'm struggling for a few weeks already.

Comment: Your ternary expression looks reasonable. What doesn't, though, is the idea of using `0..<9` in your `ForEach`. You should iterate over the moves themselves (or an array representing the squares). Without a [mre], it's impossible to provide a full-code solution.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Well, I really don't know how cold I write here the full code of my app without it being super long and messy. =/

Comment: You definitely don’t want to include your whole app — the point is to pare it down to a minimal example that represents your issue. One of the side benefits is that sometimes going through that process also reveals a solution.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help but I really don't know how to edit the code to be able to put it here. Sorry.